# Browser doesn't send a page's cookie in HTTP POST when it's contained in an IFRAME

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, browser, session-cookies, samesite

Scenario: in response to an insecure (HTTP, not HTTPS) request, a web server sends a page for domain xxx.com that contains an IFRAME whose contents is an insecure (HTTP) page for domain yyy.com (i. e. `<IFRAME src="http://yyy.com/blah`>) containing a POST-submittable form (`<FORM method=post>`).  Along w/the responses, the server sends a cookie for both pages (`Set-Cookie` for xxx.com and yyy.com), with both `Set-Cookie` headers containing the `SameSite=none` attibute.

However, when the form is submitted from within the IFRAME page, the HTTP POST request to the server does NOT contain the cookie sent to yyy.com (verified by inspection of the traffic between the browser and web server).

This behavior is noticeable on both Firefox and Chrome, and so appears to be a browser standard.

I'm confused; I thought the `SameSite=none` attribute sent by the web server was supposed to indicate to the browser that it must send the cookie belonging to an IFRAME source page whenever a GET or POST request is made by the browser for that source page's URL (regardless of whether the `referrer` line in that request has the same URL or one for another domain).

So I need an explanation as to why this isn't working, and if there's a reason why it isn't, how the problem can be resolved.  Thanks

EXPECTATION: cookie belonging to the IFRAME's src page is sent along w/the POST request (form submit) from that page

Comment: Besides the [tag:samesite] attribute, you must also check the browser settings for [tag:third-party-cookies].